# Can a dashboard be created in Jira Cloud or Confluence Cloud to display the below data set?

Tags: jira, confluence

There are Epics in Jira that have the Feature being built. There are stories within it to capture the delivery of a design, the review of the design and the code delivery. Each of these Stories have a separate Target Date. Can we represent this data in a consolidated format in Jira or Confluence?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use REST API to get data by issues/epics or by other filter data. For Server / Data Center you can use [Atlassian Java SDK](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/) to get all this data and then add it as HTML format to any Confluence page.